# How often is a programmatic created EJB Timer executed in a cluster?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer, cluster-computing

In a clustered JEE6 environment (Glassfish 3.1.2), a `@Singleton`  bean is/can be created on every cluster node. If this Singleton Bean registers a programmatic timer on its `@PostConstruct` - how often is the `@Timeout` method executed? -- on only one of that singletons (per tick), or once  (per tick) for each Singeton that registered that a timer?

*Below the code is an example what this question mean to this code.*

```
@Singleton
public class CachedService {

@Resource
private TimerService timerService;

    private static final long CACHE_TIMEOUT_DURATION_MS = 60 * 60 * 1000;

    @PostConstruct
    void initResetTimer() {
        this.timerService.createIntervalTimer(CACHE_TIMEOUT_DURATION_MS,
            CACHE_TIMEOUT_DURATION_MS,
            new TimerConfig("current user cache timeout", false));
    }

    @Timeout
    public void executeResetTimer() {
        this.clearCache();
    }
}
```

Example: The application runs on 3 nodes in a cluster. Assume the Singleton is instantiated on every node, so the `initResetTimer` is done 3 times in total (once per node). Then the question is: **is the cache cleared (`executeResetTimer` is invoked) on all nodes once per hour or not?**

*(I know that the timer ticks not at the same time on all nodes, because the Singleton is instantiated at different times, but this is not the problem/question.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure you have setup timer-service to external shared XA datasource as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beahw.html#gktqo).

Having digged into your question in past, I remember [some explanation](http://old.nabble.com/Clustered-Timer-Service-Behavior-td20945670.html) by devs in mailing-lists, that Glassfish's implementation is as follows:

> Say you have node A, B and C in a cluster. Persistent timers created
>   at node A are "owned" by node A (that is timer-events are delivered to
>   node A). If node A fails, then its timers can be migrated to another live
>   node.

Having that Glassfish [doesn't support](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beahx.html#glanq) cluster-wide `@Singletons`, you end up with as many timers as calls to `initResetTimer()`. Moreover, each server restart/redeploy will possibly create a new instance of timer per cluster node, in additions to old uncancelled ones, so don't forget to cancel your programmatically created timers :) To avoid this alltogether use declarative `@Schedule(...)` approach and Glassfish will create the timer *[once across cluster](http://www.java.net/node/695110)* and, hopefully, automatically migrate them on failure.

Hope this helps.

UPDATE:

A programmatically created timer, persistent or non-persistent, will be fired in the JVM/node it was created, regardless of clustered setup or not. You can sum up roughly: number of independent timer instances is equal to the number of calls to `timer.createXxxTimer()`

Comment: This answer was very helpfull and it answers an other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244608/how-to-run-a-scheduled-method-in-a-cluster-for-one-node-and-for-all -- But there is still one open question: In the example above the programmatic timer in NOT persistent -- will it be executed on very node (this is what I want to achieve)?

Comment: Yes, the programmatic calls to `timerService.createXXXTimer(...)` are independent from each other, see update to answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had a look at chapter 18 "Timer Service" of the EJB 3.1 spec. The app should behave according to the spec independently of clustering.

My understanding is that if `createIntervalTimer` is called once in a cluster, the timer should fire once independently on the number of nodes in the cluster. Since each singleton bean (according to your question) calls `createIntervalTimer`, the it will be execute *n* times. It is similar to [creating timers in ServletContextListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948360/ejb-3-0-timer-cluster-info).

This is theory, though. I would double-check for the specific app server you target. In glassfish, [cluster-wide timer](http://programmaremobile.blogspot.ch/2009/02/clustering-and-ejb-timer-eng.html) require to configure the timer pool with an external database.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it is not a direct amswer this could help anyway : One way that would configure only one instance per clustered environment would be to expose the singleton ejb as MXbean.
You should have to expose a managed imterface, that could even be empty , then register your ejb to the jmx service in the @PostCostruct marked method. At last you would have to provide a @PreDestroy hook to deregister from the jmx service.
This is the way suggested by the Java Champion Adam Bien.

Comment: It is a nice tick, but I do not see how it is related to my problem?

Comment: Could you link to where Adam Bien described this?